# Serve gatsby produciton with NGINX issue

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to serve my gatsby production using nginx. The site is successfully deployed and served, but I have several problems:

1. whenever I refresh on other page, it redirects to the root url
2. when I view page source on other page, it shows the source of the root 
   page (root url), not the source of the page I'm currently on

It is similar to this issue https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11196
thanks guys!

Comment: I'm having the same issue on my deployed site. If I build locally and run "serve -s public" it reproduces. If I run "serve public" it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by removing "-s" from where I was serving my public folder in my Dockerfile